# How to implement Search Functionality

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i create search bar in nav i want to search Member in nav bar and i have create bootstrap cards on home page

[image]

***This is My Member Model***

```
public class Member
    {
        [Key]
        public int MemberId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]

        public string? Name { get; set; }

        public string? Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

        public string? MaritalStatus { get; set; }

        public string? Address { get; set; }

        public long PhoneNo { get; set; }

        public string? Skills { get; set; }
        public string? Hobbies { get; set; }

        public string? JobTitle { get; set; }

        public string? Technology { get; set; }
        

        public string? ImageName { get; set; }
        public string? ImageLocation { get; set; }

        public Team? Team { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TeamMember>? TeamMembers { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ProjectMember>? ProjectMembers { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my View of search Bar

```
<form class="d-none d-md-inline-block form-inline ms-auto me-0 me-md-3 my-2 my-md-0">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="btnNavbarSearch" />
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnNavbarSearch" type="button">Search</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: What are you expecting here?

Comment: https://lucenenet.apache.org/

Comment: Could you please describe a bit more what are you trying to implement here? where do you want to implement that search result, where do you pull the member from? For this you should share your current code, the code you been shared is not enough.

Comment: i want  search  member by Member Name

Comment: i want search search functionality code or html css part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I create search bar in nav I want to search Member in nav bar and I have create bootstrap cards on home page

Though your given code is not adequate to provide a complete example
for your scenario, you could implement a search option using `ViewData` functionality roughly by following the below steps.

**How It works**

By default, we will load all the members on our Index page. Because
at the beginning `search key` will be empty. So we have set the conditional for that. After loading all the member List now we can `search`. When we enter any `search key`  it will submit the value to
the controller using `ViewData["CurrentFilter"]` and finally will
search into the database by that `search key` and return the view
back.

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult Index( string searchString)
        {
            ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;

            var members = from mem in _context.Members
                           select mem;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                members = members.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(searchString)
                                       || m.Gender.Contains(searchString));
                return View(members);
            }
           
            var memberList = _context.Members.ToList();
            return View(memberList);
            
        }
```

**Note:** Currently, we have implemented searching on `Member Name` and `Gender` you can extend to other properties as well by simply adding
`||` `or` Like this way:

```
members = members.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(searchString)
          || m.Gender.Contains(searchString || any Other Fields));
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.Member>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
<div class="form-row">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="CreateMemberView" class="btn btn-success">Create New</a>
                
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DOB)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImageName)
            </th>
            <th>
                Member Details
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DOB)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="~/ImageName/Cover/@item.ImageName"
                     class="rounded-square"
                     height="50" width="75"
                     style="border:1px"
                     asp-append-version="true" accept="image/*" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Details" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-memberId="@item.MemberId">Details</a> |  <a asp-action="EditMember" class="btn btn-warning" asp-route-memberId="@item.MemberId">Edit</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Nav Bar**

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <div class="form-row">
        <table>
            <tr>                                       
                <form method="get" action="/YourController/Index">

                              <td style="padding-right:940px">
                                 </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for..." name="SearchString" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="btnNavbarSearch" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                 </td>
                          </form>
                    </tr>
            </table>
     </div>
```

**Output**

[image]

If you need any further assistance on this, please [see our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-6.0#add-a-search-box).

Comment: Not Working when i search https://localhost:7276/Member? url changed to this nothing will happen

Comment: Did you replace this line `action="/YourController/Index"`? I don't think so. Double-check that you have copied the copy accordingly.

Comment: https://localhost:7276/HomePage/Index? now this

Comment: Did you exactly copy the code? Or missed or overriding anything?

Comment: okok i connect or i exactly copy the code